# How to indicate the database in SparkSQL over Hive in Spark 1.3

Tags: database, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a simple Scala code that retrieves data from the Hive database and creates an RDD out of the result set.  It works fine with HiveContext. The code is similar to this:

```
val hc = new HiveContext(sc)
val mySql = "select PRODUCT_CODE, DATA_UNIT from account"
hc.sql("use myDatabase")
val rdd = hc.sql(mySql).rdd
```

The version of Spark that I'm using is 1.3. The problem is that the default setting for hive.execution.engine is 'mr' that makes Hive to use MapReduce which is slow. Unfortunately I can't force it to use "spark".
I tried to use SQLContext by replacing hc = new SQLContext(sc) to see if performance will improve. With this change the line

```
hc.sql("use myDatabase")
```

is throwing the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.1] failure: ``insert'' expected but identifier use found

use myDatabase
^
```

The Spark 1.3 documentation says that SparkSQL can work with Hive tables. My question is how to indicate that I want to use a certain database instead of the default one.

Comment: Did you try the regular Hive syntax i.e. `select * from mydb.mytable`?

Comment: Yes - getting another error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Table Not Found: myDatabase.account

Answer (score 8):

### use database

is supported in later Spark versions

https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/use-database.html

You need to put the statement in two separate `spark.sql` calls like this:

```
spark.sql("use mydb")
spark.sql("select * from mytab_in_mydb").show
```

Answer (score 3):

Go back to creating the HiveContext.  The hive context gives you the ability to create a dataframe using Hive's metastore.  Spark only uses the metastore from hive, and doesn't use hive as a processing engine to retrieve the data.  So when you create the df using your sql query, its really just asking hive's metastore "Where is the data, and whats the format of the data"

Spark takes that information, and will run process against the underlying data on the HDFS.  So Spark is executing the query, not hive.

When you create the sqlContext, its removing the link between Spark and the Hive metastore, so the error is saying it doesn't understand what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you, Joe, for your comment. I was using HiveContext and noticed that the query run very slow against a large amount of data. I'm using Spark 1.3 and have no control in upgrading to 1.5+. Unfortunately in my environment 'hive.execution.engine' is set to 'mr' which makes Hive run much slower than if it was set to 'spark'. So I actually wanted to give more control to Spark by using sqlContext in running queries instead of MapReduce.
It is strange that while Spark is claiming to support Hive it doesn't understand the the database part of it which is just a sub-directory of the default one.

Comment: Hive is not doing any of the processing, so MR is not doing any of the processing.  Spark does understand the database part of it, it gets all of that information from the metastore.  SparkSQL then processes the data from the HDFS.

Comment: Joe,
Sorry, but I don't understand how it answers my question

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to implement the use databale command, but here is a workaround to use the desired database:

`spark-shell --queue QUEUENAME;
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
val res2 = sqlContext.sql("select count(1) from DB_NAME.TABLE_NAME")
res2.collect()`